# Search last actions done in facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to search all actions performed by users in my application.

Example:
My custom action: "ask"

Question: "Which users have "asked" using my application in the last 7 days?"

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no Facebook API to return that broad level of information; keep your own database if you need to do such queries